# Bash ignoring my PATH and it's cache

Tags: bash, path

I have installed pip in my ~/.local/bin/ directory.

Here are the outputs of which, type and $PATH

```
$ type pip
pip is hashed (/home/bcc/pedros/.local/bin/pip)
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
$ echo $PATH
~/.local/bin/:~/bin:~/.bin:/global/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my PATH. This is affecting other installations in my Linux as well.

My Linux:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)
```

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is not good to use in `PATH`. use `$HOME` instead. It may fix your issue (though bash does accept `~`). Also check your permissions on `pip`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! Now 'which' returns the right path.

Comment: Altought reading the related question on the comment above, I think the problem was only in the command which, not in the PATH. Not sure tho

Comment: ~ is a expansion "macro" it's not always evaluated. That's why it's better to use $HOME. It's evaluated more frequently/differently.

Comment: Yup, tested another installation that was failing before and now it worked, thanks for the help.